# How to successfully install osu! using wine1.6?

Tags: 13.04, wine, games

How can I completely and successfully install [osu!](http://osu.ppy.sh/) using wine1.6? [Here](http://osu.ppy.sh/p/download) is the download link in case anyone wanted to try. Sorry for the lack of information but thats all I could really think of adding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the Winehq Applications Database [osu!](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28025) has a Silver rating, tested on Ubuntu 13.04. You need to use the workaround at the previously mentioned link in the section called **How-to Install** in order to install it. You will also need to install these three dependencies: winetricks dotnet20 gdiplus.

---

**Update for wine 1.7**

If you are using wine 1.7 instead of wine 1.6, then follow the updated instructions for installing osu! using wine 1.7 that are given in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500483/error-extracting-setup-1-cab/500488#500488). The instructions in the linked answer will work for Ubuntu 12.04-14.04 if you add this PPA for installing wine 1.7: [ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to your software sources.

**Update for wine 2.0**

Follow the updated instructions for installing osu! using wine 2.0 that are given in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500483/error-extracting-setup-1-cab/500488#500488). The instructions in the linked answer will work for Ubuntu 16.04-18.04 if you add the Wine Staging repository for installing wine 2.0 to your software sources:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key    
sudo apt-key add Release.key    
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/    
sudo apt update
```

**Update for wine 3.0-5.0**

or in Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 you can simply type:

```
sudo apt install wine-stable # installs version 3.0
```

In Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10:

```
sudo apt install wine # installs version 4.0
```

In Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt install wine # installs version 5.0
```