# Error extracting setup 1 cab when trying to install Osu!

Tags: software-installation, wine, games

I am new to Linux and am running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I was trying to install a game called Osu! on Wine. I set up prefix in 64-bit wine version 1.7.3. When I run the .exe file of the game, an error shows up saying: `error extracting setup_1.cab.The file is not a cabinet.`

Comment: Forgot to mention. I did try installing in 32 bit prefix and other wine versions via playonlinux. I get the same error. I installed all .net components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ubuntu 16.04-18.04

1. If your computer is 64-bit, add the 32-bit architecture:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```
2. Add the Wine Staging repository:

   ```
   wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key  
   sudo apt-key add Release.key  
   sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
   ```

   Or in Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 you can skip Steps 2-4 and simply type:

   ```
   sudo apt install wine-stable
   ```
3. Update the list of available software.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
4. Install winehq-stable.

   ```
   sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
   ```
5. Create a new Wine prefix (if you don't want to use your default prefix).

   ```
   env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wineboot --init
   ```

   If Wine prompts for installing Mono, click *Cancel*.
6. Ensure that Mono is not installed (use 'wine' for 32-bit prefixes, and 'wine64' for 64-bit):

   ```
   env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wine uninstaller --remove '{E45D8920-A758-4088-B6C6-31DBB276992E}'  
   env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wine64 uninstaller --remove '{E45D8920-A758-4088-B6C6-31DBB276992E}'
   ```
7. Set reported version to Windows XP (it will ensure that the installer of .NET 4.0 will copy some required files like mscoree.dll).

   ```
   env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu winecfg
   ```

   On winecfg dialog, change reported Windows version to Windows XP, and click *OK*.
8. Download and install .NET Framework 4.0 (higher versions of .NET will not work on Wine if this version is not previously installed):

   ```
   wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-‌​4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DA‌​AE/dotNetFx40_Full_x‌​86_x64.exe
   env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wine dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /q  
   env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wineboot --restart
   ```
9. Set reported version to Windows Vista, and add mscoree.dll override.

   ```
   env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu winecfg
   ```

   Change reported Windows version to Windows Vista (because .NET 4.5 and higher don't install on Windows XP/2003, and osu! will not start if reported version is set to Windows 7 or higher).

   Go to *Libraries* tab. Add an override to mscoree and set it to "Native". Close all dialogs by clicking *OK*.
10. Download and install .NET Framework 4.6.1 (osu! Stable needs .NET 4.5 or higher to work, and Lazer needs .NET 4.6.1 or higher):

    ```
    wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/1/E4173890-A24A-4936-9FC9-AF930FE3FA40/NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe  
    env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wine NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /q  
    env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wineboot --restart
    ```

    Make sure to append the "/q" parameter after the installer path to perform a silent installation, because GUI installation of .NET 4.6.1 still doesn't work (without more workarounds) on Wine.
11. Download and install osu!:

    Stable version: (Beta and Cutting edge must be selected at osu!'s Options menu after Stable is installed):

    ```
    wget http://m1.ppy.sh/r/osu!install.exe  
    env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wine 'osu!install.exe'
    ```

    It's highly recommended to change the installation path to `C:\osu!` so you can easily find osu! files later. Then you will find them on `$HOME/.wineosu/drive_c/osu!`. Make sure to use only ASCII characters for the path to avoid installation problems.

    Lazer version:

    osu!lazer can't be installed using its default installer because it needs non-administrator privileges. Instead, download the "osulazer-full.nupkg" file from https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases and extract it inside your wine drive_c.

---

### Ubuntu 12.04-14.04

Detailed instructions to play osu! on Ubuntu (12.04 through 14.04 + variants) (x86_64)

1. Add the Official Wine PPA. From the terminal run this command:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   ```
2. Update Software Sources.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install Wine.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wine1.7
   ```

   - Accept the license for the fonts package. (Well, read it first of course. You may have to click the Terminal window and use Tab and Arrow Keys to navigate.)
4. Create a Wine Prefix Folder.

   ```
   mkdir 'Wine Prefixes'
   ```

   - Make sure your terminal is at your Home directory. (You can change directories to your home directory using the command `cd ~`)
5. Create a osu! Wine Prefix and make it a 32-bit Prefix.

   ```
   WINEPREFIX='/home/USERNAME/Wine Prefixes/osu!' WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
   ```

   - Replace USERNAME with your Linux username. (You will have to do this for the rest of these instructions.)
   - Feel free to just close the configuration window afterwards.
6. Install .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1.

   ```
   WINEPREFIX='/home/USERNAME/Wine Prefixes/osu!' winetricks dotnet20sp1
   ```
7. Download osume.exe.

   ```
   wget http://osu.ppy.sh/release/osume.exe
   ```
8. Create a osu! folder in the Program Files folder in your Wine prefix and move osume.exe to it.

   ```
   mkdir '/home/USERNAME/Wine Prefixes/osu!/drive_c/Program Files/osu!' && mv osume.exe
   ```

   - You can manually create the folders and move osume.exe with GUI also.
9. Start osume.exe

   ```
   WINEPREFIX='/home/USERNAME/Wine Prefixes/osu!' wine '/home/USERNAME/Wine Prefixes/osu!/drive_c/Program Files/osu!/osume.exe'
   ```
10. Wait for osu! update to completely download osu!

    - If you have a beatmap and/or skin library backup somewhere, now would be a good time to restore it.
11. Start osu!
12. Do any initial in-game setup you want.

    - Includes logging in, setting a resolution, changing keybindings, etc.
    - If you cannot see the login window (it appears behind osu!), set osu! to a smaller window resolution via cfg
    - If setting a fullscreen resolution causes osu! to crash and you cannot close it, see [additional notes](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28025).
13. Exit osu!

From this point on, the only thing you need to do to run osu! is just run the osu!.exe binary (double-click it or use the wine command from the terminal). You will have to create a shortcut(s) to osu! if you want. The easiest way is to go to the folder via the GUI file browser, right-click osu!.exe and make a link, and put the link on your desktop.

<sub>**Source:** [WineHQ AppDB osu!](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28025)</sub>