# winetricks .NET 4.0 Installation "Enough Disk Space Must Be Available 64Mb" Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wine, 17.04, winetricks, dotnet

I just install net with

```
WINEPREFIX=~/'Wine Prefixes/osu!' winetricks dotnet40
```

Error Screenshot:

[image]

message after exiting the installer

```
dotnet40 install completed, but installed file /home/fhadiel/Wine Prefixes/osu!/dosdevices/c:/windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/ngen.exe not found
```

Comment: And what happened after the install?

Comment: it didn't installed . but i get this message after exiting the installer dotnet40 install completed, but installed file /home/fhadiel/Wine Prefixes/osu!/dosdevices/c:/windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/ngen.exe not found

Comment: this link | http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-‌​4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DA‌​AE/dotNetFx40_Full_x‌​86_x64.exe | doesn't seems to work.

Comment: I fixed my typo error and it works now. Install .NET Framework 4.0 this way: 1. `wget http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-‌​4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DA‌​AE/dotNetFx40_Full_x‌​86_x64.exe` 2. `env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wine dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /q` 3. `env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wineosu wineboot --restart` Then download and install .NET Framework 4.6.1. [Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500483/error-extracting-setup-1-cab-when-trying-to-install-osu/500488#500488)